# What is the overview of TSR's Basic editions of D&D?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, dnd-bx, dnd-becmi, dnd-holmes-basic

There are a variety of editions of D&D published by TSR in parallel to AD&D that get collectively called “Basic D&D”, but the overall relationship of the editions to each other — and which are even separate editions — is not really obvious. It's especially not clear to the uninitiated.

What is the basic overview of these editions that would help someone trying to get a clear grip on these oft-overlooked games?

Comment: [Related] [What are the big differences between the D&D editions?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/13212)

Comment: @Adeptus Oh, good catch on the duplicate! Thanks!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It came up in the "Related" list :)